# How to remove interstitial ads from app delegate - in app purchase

Tags: ios, swift2, in-app-purchase, admob, interstitial

I have implemented interstitial ads from app delegate and it is loading fine. Now I want purchase button to remove it, and I am confused.

here is my code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var myInterstitial: GADInterstitial!


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    return true
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "xxxxx")
    interstitial.delegate = self

    interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
}

func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
    myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

and ViewController:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {


    appDelegate.myInterstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self)

}
```

Comment: And what are you confused about? What is the real question here?

Comment: how to remove ads, when you purchase it?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the real question being - How to remove ads when you purchase it (from the comments).

It can be achieved quite simply - after you receive confirmation that the purchase has succeeded you should do two things :

- set a flag in `NSUserDefaults` so that you can know about this in subsequent app launches
- set `myInterstitial` to `nil`, so that no more ads will be shown during this session

To sum up with code examples :

```
func paymentComplete() {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "userAlreadyPaid")
    appDelegate.myInterstitial = nil
}
```

And update your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to something like this :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    let userAlreadyPaid = NSUserDefauls.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("userAlreadyPaid")

    if !userAlreadyPaid {
        myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
    return true
}
```

In order to learn how to implement In App Purchases you can reference the official docs : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html

Comment: `if userAlreadyPaid` should be `if !userAlreadyPaid` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` as the `Bool` will always be `false` before the `paymentComplete()` is executed.

Comment: You are totally right! I must have mistyped it - thanks!